# How to create a seamlessly looping ocean

Tags: animation, ocean-simulation

Is there a way animate the ocean modifier so it loops continuously?

I would like to make an animation where the last frame seamlessly goes into the first without the ocean "jumping":

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please describe a little more what you tried and how the result doesn't match your expectations`?

Comment: @stacker How is it now?

Comment: That's strange, but a decent question!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From Haunt's trick bag:

[image: OCEAN LOOP]

Instead of using one *Ocean Modifier*, use two identical ones. The following values are the ones used in this example.

*Key Frames* on frame 1 and frame 21. Since these frames will be identical, the loop will only include frames 1 to 20.

First *Ocean Modifier*:

- Animate the time from 15 to 20
- Animate the scale from 0.0 to 3.0

Second *Ocean Modifier*:

- Animate the time from 20 to 25
- Animate the scale from 3.0 to 0.0

Since both Modifiers are identical, one starts exactly with the shape the other one ends with. And the scale is used to blend between them.

- Set the interpolation in the *F-graph Editor* to *Linear* (<kbd>T</kbd>) to get a constant motion.
- The *Geometry* of the second modifier must be set to *Displace*, to avoid overwriting the first.

[image]

Comment: Wow, great answer :) BTW, how did you displace only the top of your object in your example animation?

Comment: Ask the question, I'll provide the answer (:

Comment: [done](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/create-ocean-block)! :)

Comment: This works great but, if you bake it, it doesn't work. Suggestions? My goal is to use the normals for use in BGE.
Thanks

Comment: @William You should be able to mix the outputted images with an image editor or the compositor. You might also consider asking this as a new question if you need can't figure it out.

Comment: Haven't got 50 Rep here so I cannot comment (properly).
The baking issue of William is probably because in both modifiers, the same Cache path is provided. Use different paths for bakes. cheers.

Comment: I did exactly as he told above but I still get a lit jump when it loops. Any help?
A .blend file would be so great..

Comment: I did exactly as he told above but I still get a lit jump when it loops. Any help?