# Ocean modifier with volume

Tags: ocean-simulation

How can I use the *Ocean modifier* to only deform one axis of an object to create something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From Haunt's trick bag:

[image: a block of water]

Since the *Ocean modifier* doesn't use vertex groups, one solution is to get help from a modifier that does. The Ocean modifier (gray) uses an ordinary plane. The block of water is a mesh where the upper surface is highly subdivided and the bottom contains just 4 verts. It has a *Vertex Group* which excludes the four bottom verts.

The trick is a *Shrinkwrap Modifier* which is projecting the surface on the *Ocean Modifier* mesh. There the *Vertex Group* helps to leave the bottom verts in peace.

[image: shrinkwrap modifier settings]

Rendering of the *Ocean Modifier* is prevented in the outliner by clicking the camera symbol.

[image: outliner settings]

Comment: Nice one, I have been trying to do exactly this recently.

Comment: Could you please describe this for the new version of Blender? The settings now look different. There's an option "Generate" which completely replace the original geometry and it's not clear how to use Shrinkwrap modifier on... a new mesh (future ocean "volume")? Or there needs to be another way?

Comment: I would if I hadn't become a broken piece of human garbage. I am almost incapable of achieving anything by now since my learned helplessness is literally killing my by degrees and I am still using Blender 2.79.