# How to make an ocean with depth

Tags: modeling

I Tried The Ocean Modifier to make an ocean with depth like the one on the image:

[image]

but I Get A Flat Ocean. Please I Need Help

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object

Comment: Could maybe put a boolean intersect modifier on a cube, targeting the ocean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill a water domain up to where you want. Make sure the material of the water is set to glass and and IOR of 1.333. With the nodes you can tweak the look of the water even more. And don't forget to light it.

Comment: but this doesn't give it the amount of detail that the ocean modifier give you

Comment: you can add noise which would give you the same ocean results. But most of the times if you let water flow in from a good height with enough velocity, you'll get your ocean.

Comment: This way could work and is maybe the only to achieve his request, thought the ocean does give more options for detail. In the end I guess it's the users decision

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the bottom of it being deformed like the top, you can simple add a solidify modifier (with offset of -1) to achieve this effect. Otherwise, [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2868/28015) is suitable.

[image]

[image]