# Need to create realistic water volume using ocean simulation

Tags: ocean-simulation

I saw the ocean simulation modifier tutorials. There people create quite nice waves controlled by a bunch of various settings - I definitely want to use this. But the result is not very realistic from other prospective: the generated mesh is not a full-fledged 3d object and if I want to place something in the water and show the refraction, I need the mesh volume. How to create it? Extruding the generated ocean surface? Shrinkwrapping another mesh? I haven't tried the first one, but the latter doesn't look good, since I actually have two different objects with different mesh cell density...
I also need a realistic material after I deal with the first problem (probably there should be some tricks, since we have a huge water source, not just a large water-consisting object).
I still think we eventually need to have a single object with different material applied to the different faces (at least we will have a water and foam)...

UPDATE:

1. [image: setup for simplified ocean water material]
2. [image: there's no refraction applied to the underwater part of the red sphere, also there is no volumetric color, I guess because the ocean simulation is a flat object]

Comment: Can you show us more about your goal? Final look of your object? Material setup you use, camera view ... In general water material see through surface is calculated as volume (with refraction) even for default Plane object.

Comment: I have updated my question. What I want to achieve - I want to add some close-to-surface object to my initial ocean simulation, like buoy with chain or rope, some inches need to be visible if the water is clear enough... also I want to add jelly fish, etc. Probably some seaweed and another water life. I want this all to look realistic and for this purpose I need to know how to create volume and proper material for this ocean simulation.

Comment: For Extruding you can use Solidify modifier, for Shrinkwrap it [seems to be working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2865) ... but material should be enough for you https://www.blendswap.com/blend/26768 ... there is dozen of shaders or tutorials for water shader ... from screens I cant even tell if you use Eevee or Cycles ... what tutorial have you followed and where did you failed?

Comment: I've seen this tutorial by the link. It uses the same principle as the one I have followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8PSS5HqC-Q&t=76s&ab_channel=DylanNeill The problem I can see is that ocean simulation result and ocean depth object (the plane with shrinkwrap applied) are two different objects with different mesh density and they have mesh intersection which does not look right. I thought that in order to look right, this has to be a single object. Yes, I've tried to apply Solidify modifier too, but got some wild-looking mesh. I use Cycles.

Comment: Probably there would be no sense to bother with ocean volume showing just an ocean surface. But as I said, I'd like to make it different: to show some depth life. For this purpose I need a volume, not just a wavy surface. I could use water simulation for this (it allows filling something with water and get volume), but in this case I'd miss ocean simulation fine-tuning (waves, wind, foam, etc.) which seem pretty good implemented to me. I'll try to fight with Solidify modifier then...

Comment: Like I said - use just a material (for Plane with Ocean modifier) ... start with simple Glass shader ... it works for me  ... https://imgur.com/JtH6WYP