# Looping Displacement Modifier Animation

Tags: animation, vertex-groups

Background: Originally I was making a water animation using displacement null objects and needed a way to convert them to shape keys and fortunately Chipmasque provided a solution (exporting to .mdd and then importing). The problem now is that I need the animation to loop (and the water must appear to only be moving in 1 direction). Blender does not seem to be able to interpolate the vertex information well enough to maintain the illusion of movement (it will just change Z height back to the original position). I've tried changing the animation on the Null Object used to influence the vertexes, but haven't found anything that looks good (either there is an obvious "jump/snap" or the mesh has to stop, then adjust height, then start cycling again).

Actual Question:
-Does anyone know a good way to loop this type of vertex animation?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/create-looping-ocean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an animation-image-texture for that, with each frame made seemless, in an other application like gimp. That texture with the displace-modifier and Texture-Coodinates to Object. As Object I would use an plane, that plane set to not rendered an animate it with key-frames. The Interpolation-Mode set in the Graph-editor to Linear.