# Seamless looping ocean?

Tags: ocean-simulation

How can I loop an ocean animation with the ocean modifier? I really need this for a game. I want to do this so I have nice looking water!

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/how-to-create-a-seamlessly-looping-ocean

Comment: Mt Zak I saw that but didn't understand the answer. Could you simplify?

Comment: If you try to use the ocean modified, you will have **Way** too much geometry for the BGE to handle realtime.

Comment: You create 2 Ocean modifiers on the object and animate options *Time* ans *Scale* for both of them taking into account the animation begins from frame 1 and ends on 21-st. After keyframes inserted in the Dopesheet select them and press `T` > *Linear* to make this as constant loop instead of default smoothing. Further details are explained rather good there. And of course beware of adding too much geometry if this is for game.