# Creating an infinite ocean (looping)

Tags: ocean-simulation

i want to create a **looping** ocean.
im creating a time lapse animation for a ship cursing in the sea for 30 days.
i managed to animate the sky and everything else.

so i need my ocean to loop.
im using texture as ocean waves on a plane and its amazing because ocean modifier is too resource consuming.

(the ocean doesn't need to be animated as the ship will move very fast(time-lapse))

see the material im using below.
[image]

**any ideas?**

**thank you very much .**

Edit : 
Sorry for the confusion, I hope this will clarify things.

(Node setup is for reference only, I do not need to animate the actual texture) 
my question is different from the referenced question.
I'm not looking to animate the ocean. I'm looking to make it loop (physically) so my ship will be able to cruse indefinitely   (kinda) without the need to use duplicate planes as new oceans once my ship reach the end of the current plane (ocean)

Thanks.

Comment: Animate the coordinates for the displacement. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28802/2d-flow-simulation-over-a-surface/28837#28837

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a seamlessly looping ocean](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/how-to-create-a-seamlessly-looping-ocean)

Comment: For those voting to close the question as duplicate: The OP states: "I'm using texture as ocean waves on a plane (...) ocean modifier is too resource consuming"

Comment: @cegaton I don't look to animate the ocean I want it to loop physically. The animation is easy to do as you have mentioned. And I will post how I solved the atmosphere  tonight

Comment: Do you consider oldschool cinematography technique, where you move looped background instead of actual object? Something like this: https://imgur.com/a/9CTQS

Comment: @serge how can i achieve that please? thats exactly what i want. thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add a plane in Top Ortho view (numpad key 7 on Win), in Edit mode scale down Y axis, add some Bevel **CTRL B** (turn on Vertex only), select all and delete **only** faces. 
   [image]
2. Convert this mesh to Curve using **ALT C** and rotate 90 degrees on X axis in Object mode
   [image]
3. Add another plane in Top Ortho view (now it will be an ocean). Create significant amount of loopcuts to get a better transition on curve's angles
   [image]
4. Add **Array** and **Curve** modifiers to ocean plane. In Array settings select *Fit to curve* and don't forget to check *First-Last* and *Merge* options in Array to have nice loop.
5. Now you can animate X location to get loop moving

[image]

Additionally you can parent both Curve and Ocean plane to the same controlling Empty for easier manipulation in 3D space.

[image]

Comment: That must be the most graphical way of "looping" I've ever seen! :D