# infinite ocean plane

Tags: ocean-simulation

I need to render some stills of ships at sea. I've played with the ocean tool for literally days and the results I get are pretty terrible. The rendering time goes up so high it becomes impractical, and I get striping/banding whenever I do any kind of repeat. I just want a simple infinite ocean plane like I used to be able to do in Bryce 5 back in the day on a Windows 98 machine. I don't want to see any striping/tiling. How can I accomplish this.

Also, can't use cycles for this as I am automating it with a python script and the 3DS models I import in the script do not have materials/textures that work with cycles (and I have 100s of models).

Comment: I don't think that trying for 'infinite ocean plane' is a good idea. I think you should try to restrict your scene to a small area, enough for your ships, and position the camera so your renders hide the boundaries.

Comment: unfortunately for my use case that isn't possible. We are generating open sea imagery where there are no landmarks or harbors etc in sight for an ML application.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to cheat. I've given a quick look at ocean questions on this stack, maybe those could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92570/creating-an-infinite-ocean-looping?rq=1 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17787/avoiding-a-tiled-looking-ocean-simulation for example. Else there seems to be many questions about ocean, you're likely to find something helpful.