# Why does baking my ocean modifiers breaks them?

Tags: baking

##### Problem

I have two ocean modifiers to achieve a looping ocean as per [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2864/132496), however when I bake one of them or both, **the modifier seems to break** and there is no visible ocean anymore.

How can I bake these ocean modifiers ?

Scene *before* baking:
[image]

##### Update

I tried Blunder's way and **it baked something** (yay), however the final result still is different than what I had before baking in the sense that **the wave isn't looping seamlessly anymore**.
There is probably just an extra thing to take into consideration that I don't know about.

[Scene *after* baking using Blender's method (with cache)](https://easyupload.io/z9km76)

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it to bake right. There's a bug that requires a workaround to use the *Bake* button more than once [T80876](https://developer.blender.org/T80876) (File > Save + Revert instead of restart helps, too). Furthermore, you have accidentally assigned the same cache file to both modifiers. This way the data of the first modifier is overwritten when you bake the data of the second modifier. Change the value for *Bake > Cache Path* of the second modifier to *//cache_ocean_2* (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB4Mp.jpg) But this doesn't help. The output files are still all black :-( IDK why.

Comment: @Blunder Thank you very much for trying

Comment: Wait, now it's working again.... >.< It's either the *Geometry* setting or the *Grid Resolution* or both. Guess I have to test it one more time with your blend file.

Answer (score 3):

Baking these two *Ocean* modifiers is pretty weird because **there is the bug [T80876](https://developer.blender.org/T80876) that causes a weird behavior.**

**You can bake both *Ocean* modifiers with the following steps:**

1. restart Blender and open the file
2. enter two different *Cache File Paths* for each modifier, e.g. `//cache_ocean_1` and `//cache_ocean_2` so each modifier has its own cache and the data gets not overwritten. See **screenshot 1** below. It's from the blend file where it is wrong!
3. change the *Grid Resolution* to a different random value like `6`. This change is just needed to repeat the step. Press the *Bake* button. Blender will bake now the images. But if you check them they all will be black. See **screenshot 2** below.
4. do it again. Change the *Grid Resolution* to the original value (`7`). This will trigger the workaround for the bug and you can bake it again. Surprise! This time the images are backed correctly. See **screenshot 3** below.

Of course, for some reason, this trick does not work for the second modifier right now in the current state. The baked images will always be black no matter how many times you try to bake them. Blender requires a restart. So let's do this...

5. save a copy of the file (File > Save As...)
6. restart Blender
7. press the *Bake* Button of the second *Ocean* modifier. The *Bake* button will change its label to *Delete*. Congratulations! The images will be backed correctly.

**Screenshot 1:** Different *Cache Paths*. In the screenshot, they are accidentally the same. This doesn't work.

[[image: cache settings][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB4Mp.jpg)

**Screenshot 2:** Black-Backed Images

[image: black images]

**Screenshot 3:** Fine Backed Images

[image: fine backed images]

Comment: That's true, although even if I use different paths and bake them, it doesn't work, any idea why ?

Comment: It's a nasty bug. I've updated the answer. The trick is to bake the first modifier twice, then restart Blender and bake the second modifier. I hope you don't have to change anything after this procedure, otherwise you will probably have to repeat it.

Comment: I got the first modifier to bake, but the second one still is black images. X_x  
I tried twice making sure everything was right.

Comment: I tested again today and it worked, I get to bake both modifiers, however the bakes don't seem right in the sense that my wave isn't looping anymore as opposed to when it wasn't baked, so i'm basically obtaining a different result even though it bakes. :/